# how to speed up webpack build?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, webpack, uglifyjs

I'm using webpack to bundle JavaScript files and using the uglify plugin to minify them. The minification step takes longer than expected and makes the process long. Is there any way to improve the minification time (uglify plugin) for webpack?

Here's my webpack configuration:

```
/*jslint node: true */
var webpack = require("webpack"),
    _ = require("lodash"),
    path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    webpackConfig,
    commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('m-common-[chunkhash:8].js'),
    dedupePlugin = new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    uglifyPlugin = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        },
        output: {
            comments: false,
        }
    }),
    sourceMapPlugin = new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin('[file].map', null,
                                                         '[absolute-resource-path]',
                                                         '[absolute-resource-path]'),

    fnCaseSensitivityPlugin = function () {
        this.plugin('normal-module-factory', function(nmf) {
            nmf.plugin('after-resolve', function(data, done) {
                var parentDir = path.dirname(data.resource);
                var resourceName = path.basename(data.resource);
                fs.readdir(parentDir, function(err, files) {
                    if (err) {
                        done(err);
                    }
                    if (files.indexOf(resourceName) === -1) {
                        var realName = _.find(files, function(filename) {
                            return filename.toLowerCase() === resourceName.toLowerCase();
                        });
                        done(new Error('CaseSensitivityPlugin: `' + resourceName + '` does not match the corresponding file on disk `' + realName + '`'));
                        return;
                    }
                    done(null, data);
                });
            });
        });
    },

    fnDonePlugin = function () {
        this.plugin("done", function(stats) {
            var statsByChunk = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stats.toJson())).assetsByChunkName;
            webpackConfig.statsByChunk = statsByChunk;

            for (var chunkName in statsByChunk) {
                if (statsByChunk.hasOwnProperty(chunkName)) {
                    var nameIn = statsByChunk[chunkName][0],
                        gzName = nameIn.substring(0, nameIn.length - 2) + "gz.js";
                    webpackConfig.filesToCompress['./jaga-web/dist/' + gzName] = './jaga-web/dist/' + nameIn;

                    // The mrvlBuildOut object contains a set of name/value
                    // pairs to be used during HTML template processing.
                    // There are certain filenames we need to add to the
                    // mrvlBuildOut object as properties so that they can be
                    // injected into HTML templates that make use of them.
                    // The code below takes the nameIn string which will have
                    // one of 2 forms:
                    //
                    //      Debug Builds:
                    //          m-core-fixed.js
                    //
                    //      Produciton Builds:
                    //          m-core-<chunkid>.js
                    //
                    // It strips off everything after the last dash including the
                    // .js extension so we are left with the base filename. We then
                    // use that filename base to look up the name of the property
                    // we should set to that filename on the mrvlBuildOut object.

                    var map = webpackConfig.mrvlBuildOutFilePropMap,
                        propName = map[nameIn.replace(/-[^-]+\.js$/ , '')];

                    if (propName) {
                        webpackConfig.mrvlBuildOut[propName] = nameIn;
                    }
                }
            }

            webpackConfig.webpackDoneListeners.forEach(function (fnCall) {
                fnCall(statsByChunk);
            });
        });
    };

webpackConfig = {

    mrvlBuildOut: {
        //gets filled in with m-common-[chunkhash] and m-web-[chunkhash]
    },

    mrvlBuildOutFilePropMap: {
        "m-common": "jagacommon",
        "m-web":    "jagaweb",
        "m-blog":   "jagablog",
        "m-gallery":   "jagagallery",
        "m-landing":   "jagalanding",
        "m-unsupported": "jagaunsupported",
        "m-login":   "jagalogin",
        "m-voice-chrome":   "voicechrome",
        "m-apps-chrome":   "appschrome",
        "m-viewpage-chrome": "viewpagechrome"
    },

    webpackDoneListeners: [],
    filesToCompress: {
    },

    jaga: {
        addVendor: function (name, path, noparse) {
            this.resolve.alias[name] = path;
            if (noparse) {
                this.module.noParse.push(new RegExp(path));
            }
            this.entry.vendors.push(name);
        },

        addBuildOutFilePropMapEntry: function( filenameBase, propName ) {
            if ( filenameBase && propName ) {
                webpackConfig.mrvlBuildOutFilePropMap[filenameBase] = propName;
            }
        },

        stats: {
            colors: true,
            modules: true,
            reasons: false
        },
        entry: {
            'm-web': './jaga-web/js/app.js',
            'm-blog': './jaga-web/js/app-blog.js',
            'm-gallery': './jaga-web/js/app-gallery.js',
            'm-landing': './jaga-web/js/app-landing.js',
            'm-unsupported': './jaga-web/js/app-unsupported.js',
            'm-login': './jaga-web/js/app-login.js',
            'm-voice-chrome': './jaga-web/js/app-voice-chrome.js',
            'm-apps-chrome': './jaga-web/js/app-apps-chrome.js',
            'm-viewpage-chrome': './jaga-web/js/app-viewpage-chrome.js',
            vendors: []
        },
        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: [
                'node_modules',
                'jaga-web',
                'jaga-web/js'
            ],
            alias: {
                // If you find yourself wanting to add an alias here, think
                // about if it would be better for your component to live in
                // jaga-core instead of in jaga-web. See the README.md in
                // jaga-core for more info.
                'jaga-apps': __dirname + '/jaga-web/js/apps.js',
                'uuid': 'node-uuid'
            }
        },
        output: {
            path: 'jaga-web/dist',
            filename: '[name]-[chunkhash:8].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash:8].js'
        },
        module: {
            noParse: [
                /[\/\\].html$/
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            commonsPlugin,
            dedupePlugin,
            uglifyPlugin,
            fnCaseSensitivityPlugin,
            sourceMapPlugin,
            fnDonePlugin
        ]
    }
};

var libs_dir = __dirname + '/jaga-core/src/js/lib/';
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("jquery", libs_dir + "jQuery/jquery.min.js", true);
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("lodash", libs_dir + "lodash/lodash.min.js", true);
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("underscore", libs_dir + "lodash/lodash.min.js", true);
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("q", libs_dir + "q/q.js", true);
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("backbone", libs_dir + "backbone/backbone-min.js", false);//if we don't parse backbone then require is not found??
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("cookie", libs_dir + "cookie/cookie.js", true);
webpackConfig.jaga.addVendor("canvas-to-blob", libs_dir + "canvas-to-blob/canvas-to-blob.js", true);

webpackConfig.jagaDebug = {
    watch: true,
    keepAlive: true,
    stats: webpackConfig.jaga.stats,
    entry: webpackConfig.jaga.entry,
    resolve: webpackConfig.jaga.resolve,
    output: {
        path: 'jaga-web/dist',
        filename: '[name]-fixed.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name]-fixed.js'
    },
    module: webpackConfig.jaga.module,
    //devtool: "eval-source-map",
    //devtool: "source-map",
    devtool: "eval",
    addBuildOutFilePropMapEntry: webpackConfig.jaga.addBuildOutFilePropMapEntry,
    plugins: [
        commonsPlugin,
        dedupePlugin,
        fnCaseSensitivityPlugin,
        sourceMapPlugin,
        fnDonePlugin
    ]
};
webpackConfig.jagaDebug.output.pathinfo = true;

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

I'm using the grunt-webpack npm package. Here's my Gruntfile configuration for webpack

```
 webpack: {
            test: appsConfig.augmentWebpackConfig(webpackConfig.jaga),
            jagaDebug: appsConfig.augmentWebpackConfig(webpackConfig.jagaDebug)
        },
```

Note that webpackConfig refers to the configuration file above.

Comment: Do you need this to be faster for development reasons? If so the best approach would be to create a separate production Webpack config that includes the dedupe and uglify Webpack plugins. I don't know if there is an actual way to speed up uglify.

Comment: Given it's a multi-entry configuration, you could try https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack . https://github.com/amireh/happypack is another option.

Comment: remove source mapping for made it fast >>> sourceMapPlugin = new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin('[file].map', etc